# Python reading xml file with multiple namespace

Tags: python, xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <country:list version="3.0" xmlns:country="http://Some/www.home.com" xmlns:region="http://some/www.hello.com" xmlns:Location="http://Some/www.home.com">
            <country:Region111>
                <Some_child_tags>
                    <region:tag1 name="1">some contents in country:Region111 </region:tag1>

                    <tags>

                            .
                            .
                            .
                            .
                    </tags>
                    <region:tag1 name="2">Some other contents in country:Region111</region:tag1>
                </Some_child_tags>
            </country:Region111>

            <Location:Region222>
            <Some_child_tags>
                    <region:tag1 name="1">some contents in Location:Region222</region:tag1>
                    <tags>

                            .
                            .
                            .
                            .
                    </tags>
                    <region:tag1 name="2">Some other contents in Location:Region222</region:tag1>
                </Some_child_tags>
            </Location:Region222>
        </country:list>
```

> I want to retrieve all the `<region:tag1>` tag contens and attribute
>   values also that is comming under
>   `<country:Region111>...</country:Region111>` not under 
>     `<Location:Region222> ....</Location:Region222>.`       So the final
>   output should be the following

```
name 1 some contents in country:Region111                                
name 2 Some other contents in country:Region111
```

> ```
>       It should eliminate the <region:tag1> contents that is coming from <Location:Region222>.
> ```

Comment: show your efforts

Comment: don't post input xml content in comments - move it to the question

Comment: show how should look the final output considering that there are several `region:tag1` tags and they have child tags (how that childs contents should be treated) and including *attribute values(1,2)*

Comment: Updated the code with more soecification.

Answer (score 1):

Your input XML document should look as below (to be valid):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<country:list version="3.0" xmlns:country="http://Some/www.home.com" xmlns:region="http://some/www.hello.com">
<country:Region111>
     <Some_child_tags>
      <region:tag1>some contents</region:tag1>
     </Some_child_tags>
</country:Region111>
</country:list>
```

---

The solution using [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=etree#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) module:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("yourfile.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
tag1 = root.find('.//{http://some/www.hello.com}tag1')  # accessing tag with namespace

print(tag1.text)
```

The output:

```
some contents
```

Comment: Thanks for ur valuable support.

Comment: @sudarsan, welcome, you can accept the answer if it has solved the issue

Comment: The above given solution is for fetching only the first element,How can we fetch all the contents for <region:tag1>.If the xml file is looking like this.
<Some_child_tags>
      <region:tag1>some contents</region:tag1>
   .
   .
   .
   .
   <region:tag1>some other contents</region:tag1>
</Some_child_tags>

please help.

Comment: @sudarsan, update your xml and post the final output into the question